# Convert string into array in Laravel 5.5 view blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, web-frontend

```
{"id":189,"propertyType":"Hostal","propertyName":"bilal property",
 "noOfRoom":"5","streetAddress":"Street no.3 A, Albarar plaze",
 "sector":"I Islamabad","Latitude":"64","Longitude":"73","city":"Islamabad",
 "internet":"1","parking":null,"mess":"1","TvCabel":null,"RoomCleaning":"1",
 "lundary":null,"cctvCamear":null,"updated_at":"2018-04-15 10:01:10",
 "created_at":"2018-04-15 10:01:10"
}
```

`blade.php` code is

```
  {{$success}}
```

controller code is

```
       public function insertProperty(Request $request)
       {
       $user = Auth::user();
       $userID = $user->id;
       $role = $user->role; 

       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'propertyType' => 'required',
        'propertyName' => 'required',
        'noOfRoom' => 'required',
        'streetAddress' => 'required',
        'sector' => 'required',
        'city' =>'required',

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
    }


    $property['user_id'] = $request->input('user_id');
    $property['role'] = $request->input('role');
    $property['propertyType'] = $request->input('propertyType');
    $property['propertyName'] = $request->input('propertyName');
    $property['noOfRoom'] = $request->input('noOfRoom');
    $property['streetAddress'] = $request->input('streetAddress');
    $property['sector'] = $request->input('sector');
    $property['Latitude'] = $request->input('Latitude');
    $property['Longitude'] = $request->input('Longitude');
    $property['city'] = $request->input('city');
    $property['internet'] = $request->input('internet');
    $property['parking'] = $request->input('parking');
    $property['mess'] = $request->input('mess');
    $property['TvCabel'] = $request->input('TvCabel');
    $property['RoomCleaning'] = $request->input('RoomCleaning');
    $property['lundary'] = $request->input('lundary');
    $property['cctvCamear'] = $request->input('cctvCamear');




        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://hms.com/api/createProperty",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($property),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                // Set here requred headers
                "accept: */*",
                "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
                "content-type: application/json",
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.csrf_field(),


            ),
        ));
        $success= curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);





    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {

    return view('error')->with('err',$err);

    } else {

        return view('adminAction.returnproperty')->with('success',$success);
    }

}
       //api return 
       return response()->json($hostal, 201);
```

I want to convert this string  `{{$success}}` into array

Comment: try `json_decode($success, true)`

Comment: `{{$success}}` is a string. What should it contain after being converted to an array? And where is the connection to all the code you've posted?

Comment: `(array) json_decode($success, true)`

Comment: {{$success}} I write this statement into blade.php file and the result is           {"id":189,"propertyType":"Hostal","propertyName":"bilal property",
 "noOfRoom":"5","streetAddress":"Street no.3 A, Albarar plaze",
 "sector":"I Islamabad","Latitude":"64","Longitude":"73","city":"Islamabad",
 "internet":"1","parking":null,"mess":"1","TvCabel":null,"RoomCleaning":"1",
 "lundary":null,"cctvCamear":null,"updated_at":"2018-04-15 10:01:10",
 "created_at":"2018-04-15 10:01:10"
}   how to able to show this string into table? thanks

Comment: thanks everyone ,my problem has been solved  by using json_decode($success, ture);